# Dedicating a field in arbitrary class types for "external use"

Tags: c++, interface-design

My container needs to store a little information about its elements.  Normally, I store this separately from elements.  However, I'd like to give users possibility to conserve memory by dedicating a field in element structure type for external use.  E.g.:

```
struct MyStuff
{
  int           foo;
  char          bar;
  mutable char  dedicated_for_external_use;  // Because of alignment, this field
                                             // won't increase sizeof (MyStuff)
};
```

The idea here is that the field must not be accessed by anything but element's container.  Since containers store a copy (much like `std::vector`), it wouldn't be a problem if you added any given value `x` to several containers.

How would you design an interface for this that, if possible, would meet the following requirements?

- Should be completely optional.  I.e. it should be possible to *automatically* determine if given type provides such a field or not and then container would only use it if available.
- Ideally, wouldn't depend on type traits etc. as I need maximum compiler compatibility.
- Should be easy to use.  I.e. if you can and want to enable this optimization for type `MyStuff`, you could do it with 3 lines of code, not 25.  Internal complications, on the other hand, don't matter.
- Should preferably exclude false positives completely.  What I mean is: if you check for field `foo_bar` there is a small posibility that such field exists for a completely unrelated reason (and I think duck-typing is simply not for C++).  A better way would be to check if type inherits marker class `ProvidesExternalUseField` from my library, as this can't be by accident.

**EDIT**

I know about Boost.Intrusive, but what I want is something different.  If I go that way and create a hooks class with a single `char` field, it cannot be used to conserve memory in many cases.  If inherited type has an `int` as first field, `char` field will be padded to 4 bytes.  I.e. you'd often need intricate knowledge of type internals to be able to "squeeze" such extern-use field in, but inheritance doesn't really provide it:

```
struct hooks { mutable char dedicated_for_external_use; };
struct MyStuff : hooks
{
  int           foo;
  char          bar;
};
```

Here, size of `MyStuff` will be 12 bytes, not 8.

Comment: Maybe Boost.Intrusive (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/intrusive.html) and `boost::intrusive_ptr` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) might give some inspirations.

Comment: When you say "maximum compiler compatibility" what does that mean in practice? How bad are the compilers you need it to work with?

Comment: @jalf: Well, preferably it should work on a C++98-compatible compiler.  I just meant I'd prefer to do without any non-standard extensions or C++0x stuff if possible.

Comment: @Philipp: Thanks, I know about Boost.Intrusive, but what I want is a little different.  I'll better update the question.

Comment: then type traits are perfectly safe to use. They rely on C++98 features only. So define a trait like `has_extra_field<T>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial template specialization for the case your data struct derives from the marker interface.

Let's say your marker interface class looks like this:

```
class ProvidesExternalUseField
{
public:
    char GetExtraField () { return 0; }
    void SetExtraField (char newVal) {}
};
```

It is not virtual for a purpose: we wouldn't want to add a vtable pointer to a data class just  for this.

Now let's implement a simple container class:

```
template <class T>
class Container
{
public:
    char GetExtraValue ()
    {
        return 0; // here we cannot know if T is derived from the marker
    }
private:
    T m_t;
};
```

And here is how we change it to distinguish between the 2 cases:

```
template <class T, bool DoesTProvideExternalUseField>
class ContainerImpl
{
public:
    char GetExtraValue () { return 0; }

private:
    T m_t;
};

template <class T>
class ContainerImpl<T, true>
{
public:
    char GetExtraValue () { return m_t.GetExtraField(); } 
private:
    T m_t;
};

template <class T>
class Container: public ContainerImpl<T,
                                      boost::is_base_of<ProvidesExternalUseField,T>::value>
{
};
```

Now you can define the structs like this:

```
struct A
{
    int m_intVal;
};

struct B: public ProvidesExternalUseField
{
    char GetExtraField () { return m_extraField; }
    void SetExtraField (char newVal) { m_extraField = newVal; }

    int m_intVal;
    char m_charVal;
    char m_extraField;
};
```

And use the container class in the exact same way:

```
Container<A> a;
Container<B> b;
```

You can also further automate (templatize) getters and setters in the marker interface by using a poiter-to-member as a template parameter.